# copy_if function and its parameters

Tags: c++11, lambda

Would someone kindly explain what this line of code does in detail?  Please elaborate on the parameters that the function takes in.  What else is commonly used as parameters for this function?  Does the `copy_if` function only work with vectors?  I am particularly confused about the last part after the 3rd comma " [] (int x) {return x % 2; `"...

Here is the line of code I do not understand >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
`std::copy_if(array.begin(), array.end(), std::back_inserter(odds), [] (int x) {return x % 2;});`

I understand that it copies from `array` (which is a vector), and "back inserts" into the `vector<int>` odds.

Further,whenever I searched for an explanation through google, it's taken me to websites that have rather vague explanations.  Either, would someone please teach me how to understand their gibberish, or would you point me to a reliable source to learn these kinds of things?  For example, this link describes a while loop and unary predicate and I'm just lost.

Comment: Your question boils down to 1: How do iterators work? 2: What are lambdas? and 3: How do algorithms work? These are complicated things to explain, far too complex for us to get into here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity.  Where can I learn this?

Answer (score 2):

`[] (int x) {return x % 2;}`

This is just a lambda function for your precondition to be satisfied for copy.

Just see that this function when executed will give either `0` corresponding to `false`, or `1` corresponding to `true`.  If the condition/ lambda evaluates to `true`, the copy will take place else it will not.

Comment: This was helpful.  I see that I am maybe in over my head with parsing this particular bit of code.  I only have two college semesters of C++.  These courses did not even touch on this sort of thing.  Where can I learn about lambda functions and these more advanced topics?